# How can I minimise applications by clicking on its icon on dock?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

Whenever I open a single folder and if I click on the Nautilus icon in the dock, it doesn't minimize it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As I understand you want to minimise when there is a single window of the application but want to show thumbnail previews if there are more than one windows. In that case run `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-previews'` instead of the command mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: Hello @pomsky thank you very very much for your useful comment. If i could minimize multiple folders, it would be fantastic (e.g. first click on nautilus to see preview, second click to minimize/maximize).

Comment: This is a great feature for ex-Windows users. Sometimes you click an icon by mistake and want to quickly minimise it. This happens by default in Windows (version 10) and I had missed the feature on Ubuntu until activating the function after reading this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean 'minimize on click', you can activate this feature by running the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

After running this command, whenever you click on the icon of the folder/application, it will be minimized.
Here is a demo:

[image]

If you want to go back to the default settings, run the following command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: i noticed that if i run your command, i can't see the folders preview...is there a way to preserv this feature?

Comment: Well, that's the bad side of this feature. However you can overcome this problem by clicking on the top left of the screen. Normally you should have an icon or something called **Activities**, once you click on it, it will give you a preview of the opened apps.

Comment: perfect, i'll follow your suggestion

Comment: If you face any problem, mention it here and we'll try to help.

Comment: This changed my life! Thank you!